# How to check if list of objects contains a String using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, arraylist, thymeleaf

Say if I have an ArrayList with user objects into it.

User.java

```
class User{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

I have a list with users

```
list.add(new User(1,"John");
list.add(new User(2,"Sam");
```

I want to check in thymeleaf if user List is having a user with name "Sam".

```
${#lists.contains(userList.name,'Sam')}
```

But the above doesn't work and throws `Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression`

I've also tried with " (doube-quotes)

Comment: ${#lists.contains(userList,'Sam')} should work if it would be list of Strings - List<String>. But you have list of objects.

Comment: @lukasgrygar so how do I check the string contains in object properties?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [Collection Selection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) feature of [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

> 10.5.17 Collection Selection
>
> Selection is a powerful expression language feature that allows you to
>   transform some source collection into another by selecting from its
>   entries.
>
> Selection uses the syntax `?[selectionExpression]`. This will filter
>   the collection and return a new collection containing a subset of the
>   original elements.

In your particular case it would be:

```
${not userList.?[name == 'Sam'].isEmpty()}
```

Comment: What if i want to pass a variable instead of 'Sam' ?

Comment: @Arpan I can't test it now. But I guess you can do: `${not userList.?[name == someVariable].isEmpty()}`.

Comment: i tried that but the problem is that thymeleaf is searching that  'someVariable' in the object class.

Comment: @Arpan, you're right. I built a little test. The variable must be [preprocessed](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) before the expression is evaluated:  `th:if="${not userList.?[name == '__${userVar}__'].isEmpty()}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
list.add(new User(1, "John");
list.add(new User(2, "Sam");
```

Normally you can use

```
${list.contains(`Sam`)} or ${list.contains(&quot;Sam&quot;)}
```

Try this